# How to get the percentile of categories in a JSON file using Python?

Tags: python, statistics, percentile

How to count **percentiles of categories** located in an list in **Python**

I have this giant [JSON](https://lms-assets.betrybe.com/lms/books.json) to work with, assuming I'm new to Python (I do have background in programming), how can I get the percetile of each category included in the json?

I tried to at least get every category but I really don't think that the code I made is performatic.

```
def countCategory(file):
    categorieslist = list()
    for book in file:
        categories = book["categories"]
        for category in categories:
            if category not in categorieslist:
                categorieslist.append(category)
    return categorieslist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use "json.load(fp)" to read the json file, and use `extend` directly to append each item of the list to the list

```py
from collections import Counter

def countCategory(file):
    categorieslist = list()
    with open(file) as fp:
        books = json.load(fp)
    for book in books:
        categories.extend(book["categories"])
    return categorieslist

def get_category_percentage(categories):
    counter = Counter(categories)
    category_length = len(categories)
    for item, count in counter.items():
        percentage = (count / len(categories)) * 100
        print(f"{item}: {count} ({percentage:.2f}%)")
```

Comment: Using this approach, my return is all categories from all books without filtering if it exists or not, using my approach, I can at least filter them, but I cant manage to discover how I will get the percentage of it

Comment: Do you mean want the percentage of each category in all categories?

Comment: Yes, like I managed to get the total, there are 418 books in this json, but I'm trying to get the percentage of each category.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo I just add the function for getting the percentage of each category

Comment: Thank you so much @911, I'm gonna study whats happened there in the code!